# How can I put all value in list into same line

Tags: python

```py
new=None
for i in range (0,11):
  behave = ['Siberian Husky','Shiba Inu','Shiba Inu','Golden Retriever','Golden Retriever',
            'Golden Retriever','Golden Retriever','Golden Retriever',
            'Siberian Husky','Siberian Husky','Golden Retriever','Golden Retriever',
            'Golden Retriever','Shiba Inu','Shiba Inu','Shiba Inu','Shiba Inu',
            'Labrador Retriever','Labrador Retriever','Shiba Inu','Siberian Husky']
  test = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1]
  #print(len(test))
  if test[i]==1:
    new=behave[i]
    #print(new)
    
    all_new = [ x for x in new.split(',') ] 
    print(all_new)
```

I want all new show like this:

```
['Siberian Husky','Shiba Inu','Shiba Inu','Golden Retriever','Golden Retriever','Golden Retriever',
'Golden Retriever','Golden Retriever','Siberian Husky']
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand the pattern.

Comment: Why are you using `new.split(',')`? None of the strings have commas.

Comment: Now 
all_new show like this
['Siberian Husky']
['Shiba Inu']
['Shiba Inu']
['Golden Retriever']
['Golden Retriever']
['Golden Retriever']
['Golden Retriever']
['Golden Retriever']
['Siberian Husky']

how can I make it show like this
['Siberian Husky','Shiba Inu','Shiba Inu','Golden Retriever','Golden Retriever','Golden Retriever',
'Golden Retriever','Golden Retriever','Siberian Husky']

Comment: Please reformat your question, you can't simply post some code without explaining it, specify what you want to ask, maybe your code doesn't work well and what is the current output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list comprehension shouldn't be in the loop, it should be instead of the loop.

```
all_new = [behave[i] for i in range(11) if test[i] == 1]
print(all_new)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for

```
behave = ['Siberian Husky','Shiba Inu','Shiba Inu','Golden Retriever','Golden Retriever', 'Golden Retriever','Golden Retriever','Golden Retriever', 'Siberian Husky','Siberian Husky','Golden Retriever','Golden Retriever', 'Golden Retriever','Shiba Inu','Shiba Inu','Shiba Inu','Shiba Inu', 'Labrador Retriever','Labrador Retriever','Shiba Inu','Siberian Husky']
test = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1]
all_new = []
for i in range(0,11):
   if test[i]:
      all_new.append(behave[i])
print(all_new)
```

Comment: `i` is not an index in `behave`.

Comment: My bad. Changed it.